# Why do I receive a console error saying I need to define props even though they are defined in the parent and the child?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, parent-child

I am building a website using Vue JS 3 and Laravel and when I try and implement my Index.vue component I receive these errors:

> [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "label"
> [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "isDisabled"

I am pretty sure they are defined correctly in both the parent:

```js
Vue.component('biometricos', {
  props: {
    label: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    className: {
      type: String
    },
    isDisabled: {
      required: true,
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    hours: Boolean,
    minutes: Boolean,
  }
});
```

and child:

```js
props: {
  label: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  className: {
    type: String
  },
  isDisabled: {
    required: true,
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  hours: Boolean,
  minutes: Boolean,
},
```

It might make sense to declare a label like this

```html
<Component label="YourLabelHere" isDisabled="false"></Component>
```

But I don't ever call the component in this way. Plus I don't think this should be necessary with all of my declarations anyways.

Here is my full Index.vue file:

```js
<script>
import * as actions from "../../../Config/ApiUrl";
import { TableHelpers } from "./TableHelpers";
export default {
    name: "Biometricos",
    mixins: [TableHelpers],
    data() {
        return {
            momentInstance: moment(),
            searchValue: '',
            deleteLoader: false,
            isAddEditModalActive: false,
            deleteConformationModalActive: false,
            selectedUrl: '',
            tableId: '',
            rowData: {},
            time: null,
            isRunning: false,
            startTime: null,
            times: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            frameId: null,

            options: {
                name: 'position-table',
                isAddEditModalActive: false,
                url: `${actions.POSITION}/index`,
                showHeader: true,
                columns: [],
                datatableWrapper: false,
                showFilter: false,
                showSearch: false,
                showAction: false,
                actions: [],
                paginationType: "pagination",
                rowLimit: 10,
                orderBy: 'desc',
            },

        }
    },
    props: {
        label: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
        className: {
            type: String
        },
        isDisabled: {
            required: true,
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        hours: Boolean,
        minutes: Boolean,
    },
    created() {
        this.options.columns = [...this.tableColumns];
    },
    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.momentInstance = moment()
        }, 1000)
    },
    watch: {
        searchValue: function (value) {
            if (value === '')
                this.getSearchValue();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSearchValue() {
            this.$emit('input', this.searchValue);
        },
        submit() {
            this.$emit('submit');
        },
        start() {
            if (this.isRunning) throw new Error('Stopwatch has already started.');
            this.isRunning = true;
            if (!this.startTime) this.startTime = performance.now();
            this.$emit('start', this.startTime);
            this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.step);
        },
        lap(id) {
            this.$emit('lap', performance.now(), this.time, id);
        },
        pause() {
            this.isRunning = !this.isRunning
            if (this.isRunning) {
                this.startTime = performance.now()
                this.calculate(performance.now())
                this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.step)
            }
            this.$emit('pause', this.isRunning, this.time)
        },
        stop() {
            if (!this.isRunning) throw new Error('Stopwatch has not been started yet.');
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.startTime = null;
            this.times = [0, 0, 0, 0];
            this.$emit('stop', performance.now(), this.time);
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
        },
        reset() {
            this.startTime = 0;
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.times = [0, 0, 0, 0];
            this.time = this.formatTimes();
        },
        formatTimes(times = this.times) {
            const hours = pad0(times[0], 2);
            const minutes = pad0(times[1], 2);
            const seconds = pad0(times[2], 2);
            const milliseconds = pad0(Math.trunc(times[3] % 100), 2);
            if (this.hours) {
                return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}:${milliseconds}`;
            }
            if (this.minutes) {
                return `${minutes}:${seconds}:${milliseconds}`;
            }
            return `${seconds}:${milliseconds}`;
            function pad0(value, count) {
                let result = value.toString();
                while (result.length < count) {
                    result = '0' + result;
                    --count;
                }
                return result;
            }
        },
        step(timestamp) {
            if (!this.isRunning) return;
            this.calculate(timestamp);
            this.startTime = timestamp;
            this.time = this.formatTimes();
            this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.step);
        },
        calculate(timestamp) {
            const diff = timestamp - this.startTime;
            this.times[3] += diff / 10;
            if (this.times[3] >= 100) {
                this.times[3] -= 100;
                this.times[2] += 1;
            }
            if (this.times[2] >= 60) {
                this.times[2] -= 60;
                this.times[1] += 1;
            }
            if (this.times[1] >= 60) {
                this.times[1] -= 60;
                this.times[0] += 1;
            }
        },
        currentDate() {
            return new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        },
        currentTime() {
            return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        },
        clockIn() {
            this.start();

            // Get the current date and time
            const currentDate = this.currentDate();
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            // Update the table data with the current date and time
            const newIngreso = { permission_date: currentDate, ingreso: currentTime };

            // Assuming the table data is an array under 'options' property
            this.options.data.push(newIngreso);

            // Emit an event to notify the parent component to update the table view
            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
            // Open the description modal or do other tasks as needed
            console.log('Clock In button clicked');
        },
        almorzar() {
            this.pause();
            
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            const newAlmuerzo = { almuerzo: currentTime };

            this.options.data.push(newAlmuerzo);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        regresar() {
            this.pause();
            
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            const newRegreso = { regreso: currentTime };

            this.options.data.push(newRegreso);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        clockOut() {
            this.stop();
            const currentTime = this.currentTime();

            const newSale = { salido: currentTime };

            this.options.data.push(newSale);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
            this.reset();
            // store time
            // store total
            // open description modal
        },
        openAddEditModal() {
            this.isAddEditModalActive = true;
        },
        closeAddEditModal() {
            $("#demo-add-edit-Modal").modal('hide');
            this.isAddEditModalActive = false;
            this.reSetData();
        },
        reSetData() {
            this.rowData = {};
            this.selectedUrl = '';
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-side,
.right-side {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .left-side,
    .right-side {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .right-side {
        order: 2;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .left-side {
        order: 1;
    }

    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
}

.tele-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header-title {
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    color: #555555;
}

.callout.calendar-day {
    padding: .8rem 1.9rem;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    text-align: right;
}

.callout.calendar-day h1 {
    margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

.callout.calendar-day h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

.callout.calendar-day h1.light {
    color: #555555;
}

.logo {
    aspect-ratio: 1.85;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.divider-line {
    border-left: .1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
    .divider-line {
        display: none;
    }
}

.timbres {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.timbres .btn-primary {
    margin-right: 20px;
    flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-side col-sm-4">
                <div class="tele-panel">
                    <h1 class="header-title display-4">TeleTrabajo</h1>
                    <div class="callout calendar-day">
                        <div class="grid-x">
                            <div class="shrink cell">
                                <h3 class="text-primary margin-left">{{ this.momentInstance.format('DD') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"></h3>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="auto cell">
                                <h3>{{ this.momentInstance.format('[de] MMMM [de] ') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"> {{ this.momentInstance.format('YYYY') }}
                                    </h3>
                                </h3>
                                <h3>{{ this.momentInstance.format('dddd ') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"> {{ this.momentInstance.format('HH:mm:ss') }}
                                    </h3>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img loading="lazy"
                        srcSet="https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=100 100w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=200 200w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=400 400w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=800 800w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=1200 1200w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=1600 1600w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=2000 2000w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&"
                        class="logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="divider-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side col-sm-8">
                <div class="timbres mt-3 mb-3">
                    <app-button :label="$t('Ingreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false" 
                        @click="clockIn" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Almuerzo')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click="almorzar" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Regreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false" 
                        @click="regresar" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Salido')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click="openAddEditModal" />
                    <div class="search d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-with-search d-flex">
                            <span :key="'search'" class="form-control-feedback">
                                <app-icon name="search" />
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="searchValue" :placeholder="$t('search')"
                                @keydown.enter.prevent="getSearchValue" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <app-table :id="'biometricos-table'" :options="options" />
                <app-position-modal v-if="isAddEditModalActive" :table-id="tableId" :selected-url="selectedUrl"
                    @close-modal="closeAddEditModal" />
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="buttons-section col-sm-6">
                <div class="horas-square ">horas</div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening are much

Comment: Where is your template ? It is not clear where you define your components etc. It seems like you are using Single File Components, in this case, share both files.

Comment: Don't use "required" if it's not required

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks! that fixes the problem. However, I still don't understand why it's a problem in the first place given that they were declared.

Comment: "default" affects how the prop really works. "required" is a safety check that only affects console output. They are orthogonal. "required" means it's required to be specified when a comp is used like <Component :isDisabled="false">, and it seems you want to avoid this, so no "require"